# Rails: define a method to have advanced data from the db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model named `Category`. I also have a model named `Todo` (in this model there is `boolean` column `completed`).

```
Category has_many :todos
Todo belongs_to :category
```

I want to print to view all categories and for each category, how many todo are completed and how many are not are completed

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scope`:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :completed,               -> joins(:todos).where(:todos => { :completed => 1 })
  scope :not_completed,               -> joins(:todos).where(:todos => { :completed => 0 })
end
```

When you preview all categories, you can call `category.complited` or `category.not_complited`

Comment: I want to show for all category: `Category1= completed:2; not_completed:1, ecc...`. I can do this in this way?

Comment: @GiacomoCarrozzo: I had update my answer, i think it help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand how I can use this :(